# SignIn with Google, how to setup Public-facing app logo in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, google-signin

I'm logged in with Google on iOS and it redirects the app to the Google web page, where I see my app name but am not able to put the app logo on that web page.

See the picture, I want to put my logo exactly like dropbox

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to upload your logo in the Google API Console [OAuth consent screen](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent) page. Here is more information on [Setting up OAuth 2.0](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162&sjid=10663379876775862209-NA#).